# How to calculate U(n) in a recursive sequence?

Tags: python, math, sequence, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm making a program that solves "sequences" (literal translation from Dutch), however I don't know how to do this with a recursive "sequence".

Example of a recursive sequence: U(n) = U(n-1) * 3 + 2 * n
So if you want to f.e. know U(3), you first need to know U(2) and before that U(1) (which is given).

I don't know how to tell python, if the user wants to know f.e. U(7) to first calculate all the previous ones.
I believe it might be with a for ... while loop, however I don't know how that would work.
This is why there are question marks at the "answer" variable, I don't know what the formula/ for...while loop would be in python.

This is the part of the code that you need to know for my question.

```
v = int(turtle.textinput("What is v?", "v= "))
square = int(turtle.textinput("Is 'n' squared? (if not --> 1)", "square= "))
multiple = int(turtle.textinput("What is 'n' multiplied with? ", "multiple= "))

if (v != 0 and square != 0 and multiple != 0):

    WhatToKnow = int(turtle.textinput("Which U(n)?", "U(n)= "))
    answer = ????
    turtle.write(f"U({WhatToKnow}) is {answer}", font=('Courier', 30, 'italic'), align='center')

elif ...
```

to sum up my question: How do I calculated a U(n) in a recursive "sequence".

Comment: So the lowest `n` would be 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an implementation of the function `U(n) = U(n-1) * 3 + 2 * n`, with a for loop

```
val = U(1) # the starting value
for i in range(2, n+1): # loop from 2 to n
    val = val * 3 + 2 * i

print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You write it almost exactly like you said it in your description.

```
def U(n):
    if n == 1:
        return whatever-the-value-for-1-is
    return U(n-1) * 3 + 2 * n
```